# I'm trying to write a function in racket (delete-all xx elt) which returns a new list with all occurrences of elt removed

Tags: list, lisp, scheme, racket

This is what i have but it only works if the elt appear at the start of the list

```
(define (delete-all xx elt)
  (cond ((null? xx) null)
        ((equal? elt (car xx)) (delete (cdr xx) elt))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an extra case: what happens if the current element is *not* the one you want to delete? Here's the general idea of what needs to be done, I'm not giving you a straight answer because this looks like homework (you should use the `homework` tag in your question). Better fill-in the blanks yourself:

```
(define (delete-all xx elt)
  (cond ((null? xx)            ; base case: empty list
         null)                 ; return the empty list
        ((equal? elt (car xx)) ; current element needs to be removed
         <???>)                ; ignore current element and make recursive call
        (else                  ; current element needs to be added to the list
         (<???> (car xx) <???>)))) ; add current element and make recursive call
```

Also, don't call `delete` in your answer, given that this is a recursive solution, you need to call `delete-all` instead, but with appropriate arguments to keep the recursion going until the base case is reached. *Hint*: what about `cons` and `cdr`?

Comment: (define (delete-all xx elt)
  (cond ((null? xx) null)
        ((equal? elt (car xx)) (delete-all(cdr xx) elt))
        (else (cons (car xx) (delete-all (cdr xx) elt)))))

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate, it. I figured out the bug to the code. never really know that you could make more than one recursive call in a function

Comment: @Obinna great! :) please don't forget to accept the answer as correct, by clicking on the check mark to its left

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `filter`, that is if you're allowed to use [higher order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(higher-order_function)):

```
(define (delete-all xx elt)
  (filter (lambda (y) (not(eq? xx y))) elt))
```

Comment: In OP code `xx` is the list, and `elt` is the element all instances of which should be removed.

Answer (score -2):

```
(define (delete-all xx elt)
  remove* xx elt)
```

Comment: I think Obinna is trying to solve this problem using only the simpler library functions (it looks like a coursework question).  Using remove* would be cheating and it's hard to see your answer as serious.